# Omnipay: Alipay (Global) complete purchase: only scalar values allowed

Tags: php, symfony, omnipay

I am integrating Alipay payments into my webshop and I use [omnipay-global-alipay](https://github.com/lokielse/omnipay-global-alipay). Everything from the guide works until the 'Notify' part. 
When I try to add the `request_params` with `array_merge($_GET, $_POST)`  it gives the error:
`500: Only scalar values are allowed for parameters`

But without an array it will complain that I need to add the `sign_type` and `sign` to the `request_params`. The error is: `500:The sign_type of request_params is required`
The array_merge result looks like this:

```
            [
                "sign" => "random sign* 2370cbc2296f",
                "trade_no" => "random trade_no* 840200359052",
                "total_fee" => "0.01",
                "sign_type" => "MD5",
                "out_trade_no" => "58d25fc13f930",
                "trade_status" => "TRADE_FINISHED",
                "currency" => "USD"
            ]
```

**not showing the complete sign for security reasons*
If someone knows the answer to this question, please do tell.

edit:
some more information. The website is written in the framework Symfony2. the method that processes the data looks like:

```
 /**

 * @Route("/payment/success/status/{paymentMethod}", name="paymentStatus", defaults={"paymentMethod" = null})

 */

public function paymentStatus($paymentMethod){

    $this->updateKeys();

    if(strtolower($paymentMethod)=="mollie") {

        $gateway = Omnipay::create($this::MOLLIE);

        $payment = $gateway->payments->get($_POST["id"]);

    }elseif(strtolower($paymentMethod)=="alipay"){

        /**

         * @var Omnipay\GlobalAlipay\WebGateway $gateway

         */

        $gateway = Omnipay::create('GlobalAlipay_Web');

        if($provider && $provider->getApiData() && $provider->getApiData()->getAlipayCheck()) {

            $gateway->setPartner($provider->getApiData()->getAlipayPartnerId());

            $gateway->setKey($provider->getApiData()->getAlipayKey());

            //^for sign_type=MD5

        }else{

            $gateway->setPartner    ($this->alipay_partner_id           );

            $gateway->setKey        ($this->alipay_api_key              );

            //^for sign_type=MD5

        }



        $gateway->setEnvironment('sandbox');

        //^for Sandbox Test (Web/Wap)

        $params = [

            'request_params' => array_merge($_GET, $_POST)

        ];

        $payment = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();



    }
```

the data that is sent by alipay:

```
sign=ac4ee758012e2e3&trade_no=2017032221&total_fee=0.01&sign_type=MD5&out_trade_no=58d25f3f930&trade_status=TRADE_FINISHED&currency=USD
```

Comment: "everything from the guide works until ..." -- what guide are you referring to?  As far as I know, AliPay doesn't require the request parameters in the notify to be sent back to it during completePurchase().

Comment: the guide that is specified on [omnipay-global-alipay ](https://github.com/lokielse/omnipay-global-alipay).

Comment: but the problem was already solved, forgot to close this thread. The solution was in that I used an older version of the package. after updating the package everything worked again